# UITableView One Row Per PLIST Found in Documents Folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

My app can create little slide shows, and it saves the NSMutableArray as a PLIST.  So, there can be multiple PLIST files in the Documents.  What I would like to accomplish is to have a TableView with 1 Row per PLIST in the Documents folder.  How might I be able to accomplish this?  I've seen the guides for making a TableView from a PLIST (which is what I do in the next step), but not for just showing all the PLISTS in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Why don't you use `CoreData` for storing your slide show definitions? It's much better for organising data than Plists.

If it has to be Plists, just get the contents of the `Documents` directory with `NSFileManager`, and filter the resulting array of files with an `NSPredicate` on the plist extension. Then use the filtered array as source for your table view.